# A weird bug in Raspian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, update, pi-3b+, desktop

I just updated my Raspberry pi 3B+, after the reboot all windows get their “top” cut of like this:[image]
And everytime the cursor is outside the current window it appears as an “x”, I hope you can help me out with how to restore a normal desktop experience

Other weird stuff:

Apps/Windows don’t appear in the dock after launch,

The menu button on the far left off the “dock” doesn’t appear graphically at all

At first boot my desktop wallpaper were all black

Comment: Tried changing the resoloution and toggled overscan

Comment: It is not a bug, it is the settings, Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43676077/4902099) on how to change the settings

Comment: @hcheung as you Can See In the comment above, I’ve already changed my resolution, but thank you for trying